# vue ionic problem using icons that include "-" in name Example "arrow-back"

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

import { arrow-black } from 'ionicons/icons';

when Export with Return the "arrow-black" The App give Error: ", expect"

Answer (score 2):

`"arrow-back"` is an invalid identifier because of the hyphen, so it wouldn't be possible to export/import that.

However, the package actually [exports `"arrowBack"`](https://unpkg.com/browse/ionicons@5.5.2/icons/index.d.ts). Any hyphenated icon name found in [the catalog](https://ionic.io/ionicons) should be converted to camel-case when importing.

So the correct import would be:

```js
import { arrowBack } from 'ionicons/icons'
```